# v2rayA and Qv2ray don't work systemwide

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, arch-linux

I live in Iran and to bypass the filtering, I have resorted to v2ray and shadowsocks since most VPNS are blocked in my country. On my phone, I use V2rayNG which works just fine for vmess and shadowsocks servers, but on my Arch Linux, I have tried both v2rayA and Qv2ray and they share a very interesting behaviour in common, they don't work at all.

So I would add the same servers I would on my phone that work, then I would delay test them on v2rayA and Qv2ray, and they would return the same result that they would on my phone, then I would connect and both applications would report that I have connected, but when I try any services that are blocked in my country, it would be as if I'm not using any proxy/vpn at all!

Another interesting thing I found out is, in Qv2ray, it has a network usage graph, and when real-delay testing WITHIN the app, the graph would spike up, but no matter what I do outside the app the network usage would not go up.

I firmly believe it has to do with how my system is set up, given that I can use the proxies on the same network on my phone. Can anybody guide me on how I could begin to troubleshoot this? Like what logs would I need to check or what configurations I need to edit

EDIT: Setting qv2ray to also port forward socks to 1089 and using that in my browsers default proxy makes it work! but i have no idea how to make it work for my games and other apps that do not have proxy settings

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I also ran into this issue today. The key to fix it was to enable [Transparent Proxy](https://v2raya.org/en/docs/prologue/quick-start/#transparent-proxy) in V2RayA settings. There could be a similar settings item in other clients as well.